# Using equalTo filter to display data in angularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'd like to populate data from firebase to my angular page. I have a field called `isActive` and by default, it's set to `false`. What I would like to do specifically is to display data only `isActive = true`. 
To accomplish this, I used `equalTo` filter in the `angularFire2`. But my html shows no data. Here is my firebase database looks like:

```json
{
  "-KxTcvT8K1aOhuHOa4xx" : {
  "category" : "Angular 2/4+",
  "createdDate" : 1509121308599,
  "imageUrl" : "",
  "isActive" : true,
  "name" : "Sample test 1",
  "title" : "test"
},
  "-KxTdpCOA6eElekGECpr" : {
  "category" : "Machine Learning",
  "createdDate" : 1509121545084,
  "imageUrl" : "",
  "isActive" : false,
  "name" : "Sample Test 2",
  "title" : "second test"
 }
}
```

And my component is like below:

```js
  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/posts', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'createdDate',
        equalTo: 'isActive'
      }
    });
  }
```

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace yours with this, disclaimer: the way I get your data in `/posts` is my coding preference, you can tweak this snippet with yours.

**lorem.service.ts**

```
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireAction, DatabaseSnapshot, DatabaseReference } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

...

  get getAll(){
    // get data with list
    const list = this.db.list<any>('/posts', (query: DatabaseReference) => {
      return query.orderByChild('createdDate').equalTo('isActive');
    });

    // return key and values, insert list
    return this.mapNewChanges(list);
  }


  // HELPER

  private mapNewChanges(list: AngularFireList<any>): Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot>[]> {

    // return key and values from `/posts`
    return list.snapshotChanges()
      .map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      });
  }
```

**lorem.component.ts**

```
  public items: Observable<any> | AngularFireObject<any> | AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(private loremService: loremService) { }

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.items = this.queryService.getAll;        
  }

  readAll(): void {
    console.log(this.items)
  }
```

Look at `readAll()` and how I log the items. you can use the items to display your data in html.